# Getting rid of Codec log from VFW(Video for Windows)

Tags: video, codec, vfw

Whenever I'm trying to record a video from a game, using x264vfw codec, I get this log message, which makes my game minimize and which inevitably makes my tool record black screen, for a few seconds until I resume the game.How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See posts under "Discussion" [there](https://sourceforge.net/p/x264vfw/support-requests/5/):

> You have few options:
>
> 1) As you already find out you can set "Log level" to "None". In registry this  would be "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\GNU\x264\log_level" set to 0 (or "x264vfw64" instead of "x264" for 64-bit version). But this way you are fixing symptoms without fixing reason why this warning (default Log level) is showed.
>
> 2) You can fix the reason of warnings (which warns about possible lost frames due buffering and possible audio desync with you settings). In your use case you probably should enable "Zero Latency" option ("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\GNU\x264\zerolatency" set to 1) if this is acceptable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering  .I dont have any x264 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\GNU

Comment: So you can create it. Also, you have the option to change log level via setup GUI as described in the ticket at sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10 (which was my case), a solution that does exactly what the other answer does (but automatically, without editing the registry) is to run `Configure x264vfw` and `Configure x264vfw64` from the x264vfw installation package **as administrator** and set the `Log Level` to `None` while checking the `Zero Latency` option. This creates the required registry keys and also eliminates the log window.

Roman R.'s solution is preferable if you want to achieve this programatically (like it seems from your screenshot). My answer is just an alternative for people that are not interested in doing this at runtime.